# How to format a floating point for display based on locale environment variables?

Tags: bash, floating-point, locale

Lets say I have several floating point numbers to print in a Bash script.
But I want the floating points numbers displayed accordingly to the `LC_NUMERIC` locale environment variable.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# For consistent/reproducible error messages in this sample code
LANGUAGE=C

# The speed of light in vacum in m.s
declare -r const_C=299792458

# Declare separately when assigning command output
declare -- const_pi

# π is 4 × arc-tangent of 1, using bc calculator with math library
typeset -r const_pi="$(bc --mathlib <<<'scale=20; 4*a(1)')"

# Do it in US's English
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.utf8
printf 'LC_NUMERIC=%s\n' "${LC_NUMERIC}"
printf 'Speed of light in vacuum is:\nC=%.f m/s\n\nπ=%.10f\n' \
  "${const_C}" \
  "${const_pi}"

echo $'\n'

# Do it in France's French
# it fails because floating point format
# changes for printf parameters
LC_NUMERIC=fr_FR.utf8
printf 'LC_NUMERIC=%s\n' "${LC_NUMERIC}"
printf 'La vitesse de la lumière dans le vide est :\nC=%.f m/s\n\nπ≈%.10f\n' \
  "${const_C}" \
  "${const_pi}"
```

Actual output:

```
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.utf8
Speed of light in vacuum is:
C=299792458 m/s

π=3.1415926536


LC_NUMERIC=fr_FR.utf8
La vitesse de la lumière dans le vide est :
C=299792458 m/s

a.sh: line 29: printf: 3.14159265358979323844: invalid number
π≈3,0000000000
```

This is a perfectly expected result because `printf` `%f` format expects the argument be formatted according to `LC_NUMERIC`.

Then how do you display arbitrary floating-point numbers that are stored in POSIX or `bc`'s format but having display reflect the settings of `LC_NUMERIC`?

What if I want the French part of the code, with the following output?

Expected output for French:

```
La vitesse de la lumière dans le vide est :
C=299792458 m/s

π≈3,1415926536
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a problem with Bash's own built in printf command. The standalone printf works OK.

```
LC_NUMERIC=fr_FR.UTF8     printf 'Bad  : %f\n' 3.14
env LC_NUMERIC=fr_FR.UTF8 printf 'Good : %f\n' 3.14
```

Output

```
script.sh: line 4: printf: 3.14: invalid number
Bad  : 0,000000
Good : 3,140000
```

Comment: Great to know the difference between the built-in `printf` and the `printf` _command_. Do you know if the `printf` _command_ implementation is stable and reliable across platforms?

Comment: @LéaGris I'd guess printf is *more* stable than bash across platforms. `printf` is specified by POSIX, `bash` is not.

Comment: It is likely worth of a ShellCheck warning if using the built-in `printf` with '%f' in the format string, be sure to either set `LC_NUMERIC=C` or `LC_NUMERIC=POSIX` and have all floating-point number parameters properly formatted. Or use the preferred stand-alone `printf`command.

Comment: Submitted as [ShellCheck issue #1638](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/issues/1638)

Comment: I created a Bash library and stand-alone command for locale format conversion of numbers `lcnumconv.sh` to not only help deal with the issue of the built-in `printf %f`, but also convert input or any place where you need to deal with locale formatted numbers. It Is available here as free software: https://github.com/leagris/lcnumconv.sh