# Bash - echo percentage with no decimal point with result returned from bc command

Tags: bash, bc

I use `bc` for a simple percentage calculation. What I am trying to do is print out percentage in integer format, for example:

> Compression ratio: 72%

Here is what I am doing:

```
echo "Compression ratio: $(bc <<< "scale=2; $output_size / $input_size * 100")%";
```

Which produces the following output:

> Compression ratio: 72.00%

I know the cause of the issue, which was the `scale=2`. Changing it to `scale=0` causes `$output_size / $input_size` which is 0.72 to be rounded to 0 before being multiplied with 100 which results in an undesirable output.

I tried these but they didn't work:

```
echo "Compression ratio: $(bc <<< "scale=2; $output_size / $input_size" * 100)%";
echo "Compression ratio: $((bc <<< "scale=2; $output_size / $input_size" * 100))%";
```

How to put `* 100` outside of `bc` correctly?

Comment: `echo .72 | awk '{printf "%2.0f%%\n", 100 * $1}'`

Comment: `echo .72 | awk '{print 100 * $1}' | xargs printf '%2.0f%%\n'`

Comment: `echo .72 | tr -d . | xargs printf '%2.0f%%\n'`

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thanks, they solve the problem, except for the fact that I must put `echo -n "Compression ratio:";` on a separate line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this approach:

```
echo "Compression ratio: $(bc <<< "scale=2; x = 8 / 7 * 100; scale = 0; x / 1")%";
```

Output:

```
Compression ratio: 114%
```

Comment: I decided to go with the `printf` option suggested above. Although your code snippet is not very clean, it does match my question.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use echo.  Printf lets you specify a format string:

```
printf "Compression ratio: %2.0f%%\n" "$(bc <<< "scale=2; $output_size / $input_size * 100")"
```

Comment: ./compress.sh: line 90: printf: 72.00: invalid number ___ It seems `printf` expected an integer instead.

Comment: @Livy, fixed it

Comment: @jeremysprofile Um, I did not see what you edit. `$(bc <<< "scale=2; 72 / 100 * 100")` results in `0.72 * 100` and the final result is `72.00`, which is considered an invalid number for `printf`.

Comment: use stand-alone `printf` command rather than Bash's built-in `printf` with `env printf '%q'`. Because Bash's built-in `printf` is broken when formatting floating-point number, requiring the floating-point number parameter be expressed into the local `LC_NUMERIC` format rather than the POSIX floating-point number representation. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56909997/7939871

Comment: @Livy, for me, it was not working with the quotes around the `$(bc...)` subshell.

Answer (score 0):

Using shell built-in integer arithmetic:

```sh
echo "Compression ratio: $(((100*output_size)/input_size))%"
```

Using `bc` calculator and flating-point number format with `env printf` (1) :

```sh
env printf "Compression ratio: %.0f%%\n" $(bc <<< "scale=2; $output_size / $input_size * 100")
```

---

1. Do not use Bash built-in `printf '%f' ${value}` to format floating-point numbers because it requires the `value` to be formatted according to the environment variable `LC_NUMERIC` rather than accepting the POSIX format.